# How to detect if a dictionary is empty or null

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsdictionary

I am receiving a JSON string that I need to iterate to retrieve some objects values.
This is the structure

```
-meta
-objects
   |_cabdriver
              |_employee
   |client
```

There are objects under the objects tree and there are also child nodes, like cabdriver and client. The child node cabdriver has also another child node called employee.

This is the way I am iterating it:

```
NSArray *messageArray = [json objectForKey:@"objects"];
historialServicios = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

// Parse and loop through the JSON
for (dictionary in messageArray) {
    //datos de nivel objects
    NSString * date = [dictionary objectForKey:@"date"];
    NSString * origin = [dictionary objectForKey:@"origin"];
    NSString * destiny = [dictionary objectForKey:@"destiny"];
    NSString * rate = [dictionary objectForKey:@"service_rate"];
    NSString * state = [dictionary objectForKey:@"state"];
    NSString * time_service = [dictionary objectForKey:@"time_service"];
    NSString * id_service = [dictionary objectForKey:@"id"];

    //datos de nivel cliente
    NSDictionary *level2Dict = [dictionary objectForKey:@"client"];
    NSString *client_id = [level2Dict objectForKey:@"id"];

    //datos de nivel cabdriver
    NSDictionary *cabdriverLevelDict=[dictionary objectForKey:@"cabdriver"];

    //datos de nivel employee
    NSDictionary *employeeLevelDict = [cabdriverLevelDict objectForKey:@"employee"];

    //datos del employee
    NSString *driverName = [employeeLevelDict objectForKey:@"name"];
    NSString *driverLastname = [employeeLevelDict objectForKey:@"lastname"];
    NSString *driverPhone = [employeeLevelDict objectForKey:@"phone"];
    NSString *driverId = [employeeLevelDict objectForKey:@"id"];

    [historialServicios addObject:@{
                                   @"time_service": time_service,
                                   @"id_service": id_service,
                                   @"rate": rate,
                                   @"destiny": destiny,
                                   @"state": state,
                                   @"origin": origin,
                                   @"client_id":client_id,
                                   @"date": date,
                                   @"driverName":driverName,
                                   @"driverLastname": driverLastname,
                                   @"driverPhone": driverPhone,
                                   @"driverId": driverId

                                   }];
    NSLog(@"DESPUES DE ANADIR OBJETOS");
    NSLog(@"OBJETO ANADIDO==>TIME SERVICE = %@, ID SERVICE=%@, SERVICE RATE=%@,SERVICE DATE=%@,DESTINY=%@, STATE =%@,CLIENT ID=%@, ORIGIN=%@,DRIVER NAME=%@, DRIVER LASTNAME=%@,DRIVER PHONE=%@, DRIVER ID=%@",time_service,id_service,rate,date,destiny,state,client_id,origin,driverName,driverLastname,driverPhone,driverId);

    //insertamos objetos en diccionario historialServicios
}
```

Everything works fine if the object has all nodes but some times, the node cabdriver is empty and doesn't have the employee child node. If it is the case I get an exception is thrown and the app crashes.

How can I determined if the node employee doesn't exist and avoid to get the exception?

Thank you.

Comment: You have mentioned that you get an exception, but you have not described it. On which line does the exception occur? What is the exception stack trace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could declare a category to deal with the `[NSNull null]` values that are injected into your json.

```
@interface NSDictionary (NilNull)
- (id)optionalObjectForKey:(id)key;
- (id)optionalObjectForKey:(id)key defaultValue:(id)defaultValue;
@end

@implementation NSDictionary (NilNull)
- (id)optionalObjectForKey:(id)key {
  return [self optionalObjectForKey:key defaultValue:nil];
]
- (id)optionalObjectForKey:(id)key defaultValue:(id)defaultValue {
  id obj = [self objectForKey:key];
  return (obj == [NSNull null] || !obj) ? defaultValue : obj;
}
@end
```

Then use that instead:

```
NSDictionary *cabdriverLevelDict = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"cabdriver"];
NSDictionary *employeeLevelDict = [cabdriverLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"employee"];
```

---

You haven't posted the contents of your exception, but from the looks of it, it's probably related to trying to add `nil` values to your new dictionary.

Then use a default value of `[NSNull null]` for all your data lookups that produce objects with which you will construct your final dictionary. The full lookup source will now be like this:

```
NSString * date = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"date" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * origin = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"origin" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * destiny = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"destiny" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * rate = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"service_rate" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * state = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"state" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * time_service = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"time_service" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString * id_service = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"id" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];

//datos de nivel cliente
NSDictionary *level2Dict = [dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"client" defaultValue:[NSDictionary dictionary]];
NSString *client_id = [level2Dict optionalObjectForKey:@"id" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];

//datos de nivel cabdriver
NSDictionary *cabdriverLevelDict=[dictionary optionalObjectForKey:@"cabdriver" defaultValue:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

//datos de nivel employee
NSDictionary *employeeLevelDict = [cabdriverLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"employee" defaultValue:[NSDictionary dictionary]];

//datos del employee
NSString *driverName = [employeeLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"name" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString *driverLastname = [employeeLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"lastname" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString *driverPhone = [employeeLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"phone" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
NSString *driverId = [employeeLevelDict optionalObjectForKey:@"id" defaultValue:[NSNull null]];
```

Comment: If you created methods like dictOrNilForKey which return either an NSDictionary* or nil, that would be much more useful. Or stringOrNilForKey guaranteed to return an NSString* or nil.

Comment: @gnasher729: That would not be more useful for the OP's requirements. The requirement for constructing his dictionary (`[historialServicios addObject:@{ ... }]`) is that the objects added to the dictionary be **not** `nil`. This is why I specifically created the methods that return a default value on either `[NSNull null]` **or** `nil`.

Comment: Thank you Ian, what do you mean with declare a category? Should I create a new class from type NSDictionary?

Comment: I wrote the category source for you. See `@interface NSDictionary (NilNull)` category.

Comment: I have seen it, but I have never created a category source, how should I implement i? Do I need to create a new class to out the code inside?

Answer (score 1):

Try this here:

```
if( cabdriverLevelDict.allkeys.count ){
    // Do something with the dict
} else {
    // dict is empty
}
```

Comment: You just copied all the keys in the dictionary for no reason. Huge waste of CPU and memory. NSDictionary has a count method itself, so use cabdriverLevelDict.count.

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.

Answer (score 1):

Basically, you need to check every single result that you get. If you don't do that, your app is open to attacks, and one attack might allow a hacker into the user's device and cause unlimited damage. Where you expect a dictionary, you might get nil, you might get a null, you might get a number, or a string, just anything. It's quite simple.

```
NSDictionary* dict = ...; 
if (! [dict isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]]) dict = nil;
```

In Objective-C, nil objects are quite safe. You can use objectForKey [@"employee"], for example, and all that will happen is that you get nil as the result. And you could have received nil anyway.

There is no point checking for [NSNull null] only, because any other result that the server gave you will crash your app just the same. Just check for what you actually expect. Throwing away incorrect data is fine, after all the JSON deserialiser will throw away everything if just a single byte of data is wrong.

Sometimes you need to do a bit more care because servers misbehave and you have to cope with it. For example, a server supposed to return an array of dictionaries might give you just a dictionary if there is only one, so you would check for example

```
NSArray* arrayOfDicts = ...;
if ([arrayOfDicts isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]] arrayOfDicts = @[arrayOfDicts];
else if (! [arrayOfDicts isKindOfClass:[NSArray class]] arrayOfDicts = nil;
```

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.

Answer (score 1):

As others have pointed out, if any of the objects passed into the dictionary are nil, that will throw an exception that crashes your app. By doing the following:

```
 [historialServicios addObject:@{
                               @"time_service": time_service,
                               @"id_service": id_service,
                               @"rate": rate,
                               @"destiny": destiny,
                               @"state": state,
                               @"origin": origin,
                               @"client_id":client_id,
                               @"date": date,
                               @"driverName":driverName,
                               @"driverLastname": driverLastname,
                               @"driverPhone": driverPhone,
                               @"driverId": driverId

                               }];
```

You're depending that all these objects (eg time_service, id_service, etc) are not nil. As you've pointed out, they can be nil, so you need to have a means of checking for each object you do. I would recommend using an NSMutableDictionary, making a category method that only adds the key/value pair if they are both not nil:

```
@implementation NSMutableDictionary (Util)

-(void)setObjectOrRemoveIfNil:(id)anObject forKey:(id<NSCopying>)aKey
{
    if (anObject == nil)
    {
        [self removeObjectForKey:aKey];
    }
    else
    {
        [self setObject:anObject forKey:aKey];
    }
}

@end
```

And then put together your dictionary like so:

```
NSMutableDictionary* values = [NSMutableDictionary dictionary];
[values setObjectOrRemoveIfNil:time_service forKey:@"time_service"];
[values setObjectOrRemoveIfNil:id_service forKey:@"id_service"];
//Keep going with the rest of your values.
```

Finally we use that dictionary like you did already:

```
 [historialServicios addObject:values];
```

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.

Answer (score 0):

check the count for the dictionary

```
if ([cabdriverLevelDict count] == 0) {
 NSLog("empty");
}
else{
 // Do your stuff !!
}
```

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.

Answer (score 0):

```
if (![cabdriverLevelDict isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]] ){
    //do something
}
```

try this

Comment: What if the `NSDictionary` is already initialized? Then the condition would be true even there are no objects

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.

Answer (score -2):

You can try

```
NSDictionary *employeeLevelDict = [cabdriverLevelDict objectForKey:@"employee"];


if (employeeLevelDict.count != 0)
{             
     // do something if dict is not empty
}
else
{

}];
```

Comment: Does it really need to copy the whole code for 2 important lines of code?

Comment: Than you, but I would prefer the answer form Ian.